# Seeking efficient way to compare and filter overlaps in Pandas date ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns containing date ranges.

The original data looks something like this:

```
df1:
personid, visitto, intime, outtime
8, 8, 2017-07-01 06:00:00, 2017-07-01 08:00:00
17 8, 2017-07-02 09:00:00, 2017-07-02 10:00:00

df2:
location, open, close
8, 2017-07-01 04:00:00, 2017-07-01 13:00:00
```

Here's what I have done so far:
1.  Merge the two dataframes on visitto->location

```
merged_df:
personid, visitto, intime, outtime, location, open, close
8, 8, 2017-07-01 06:00:00, 2017-07-01 08:00:00, 8, 2017-07-01 04:00:00, 2017-07-01 13:00:00
17 8, 2017-07-02 09:00:00, 2017-07-02 10:00:00, 8, 2017-07-01 04:00:00, 2017-07-01 13:00:00
```

2. Convert the four columns with dates to pandas intervals

```
personid, visitto, visittime, opentime
8, 8, [2017-07-01 06:00:00, 2017-07-01 08:00:00], [2017-07-01 04:00:00, 2017-07-01 13:00:00]
17 8, [2017-07-02 09:00:00, 2017-07-02 10:00:00], [2017-07-01 04:00:00, 2017-07-01 13:00:00]
```

I now want to filter this merged dataframe of intervals to only return rows where the datetimes overlap.  My expected result would be:

```
personid, visitto, visittime, opentime
8, 8, [2017-07-01 06:00:00, 2017-07-01 08:00:00], [2017-07-01 04:00:00, 2017-07-01 13:00:00]
```

I successfully was able to get to the desired outcome using iterrows() and comparing the overlaps line-by-line, however, this is extremely verbose.  What I would prefer to do is something like (non-working example):

```
merged_df.loc[merged_df['visittime'].overlaps(merged_df['opentime'])]
```

Or, accomplish this during the merge of the dataframes.  Something along the lines of (non-working example):

```
merge_df = pd.merge(df1[["personid", "visitto", "intime", "outtime"]], df2[["location", "open", "close"]], how='inner', left_on='visitto', right_on='location') #WHERE intime, outtime OVERLAPS open, close
```

Is it possible to perform this operation from a Pandas function rather than looping?  This can easily be done from Sql in the database, however, I am struggling to find an efficient way to perform this operation on the dataframe.

Comment: doesn't the merge multiply the data? you get df1 x df2 rows, right? i assume this could lead to problems on fairly large datasets....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating compound object columns (like `list`s), which you will *always* have to iterate over, use the builtin pandas `datetime` functionality (plus the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)):

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv_buff = StringIO("""personid,visitto,intime,outtime,location,open,close
8,8,2017-07-01 06:00:00,2017-07-01 08:00:00,8,2017-07-01 04:00:00,2017-07-01 13:00:00
17,8,2017-07-02 09:00:00,2017-07-02 10:00:00, 8,2017-07-01 04:00:00,2017-07-01 13:00:00""")
csv_buff.seek(0)
dtypes = {
    "intime": "datetime64",
    "outtime": "datetime64",
    "open": "datetime64",
    "close": "datetime64"
}
df = pd.read_csv(csv_buff).astype(dtypes)

df[(df["intime"] <= df["close"]) & (df["open"] <= df["outtime"])]
```

Results in:

```
   personid visitto              intime             outtime  location                open               close
0         8       8 2017-07-01 06:00:00 2017-07-01 08:00:00         8 2017-07-01 04:00:00 2017-07-01 13:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's still fundamentally a loop, this does accomplish this.

```
merged_df[merged_df.apply(lambda x: x['in1'].overlaps(x['in2']), axis = 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `IntervalIndex` with your pandas:

```
df1['visittime'] = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left=df1.intime,
                                                right=df1.outtime,
                                                closed='both')

df2['worktime'] = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left=df2['open'],
                                               right=df2['close'],
                                               closed='both')

new_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='visitto', right_on='location', how='left')
new_df.loc[[a.overlaps(b) for a, b in zip(new_df['visittime'], new_df['worktime']) ]
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all "time" colums are of *datetime* type.

Start from converting both times to an *Interval* and dropping
(now redundant) source time columns (in both DataFrames):

```
df1['visittime'] = df1.apply(lambda row: pd.Interval(
    row.intime, row.outtime, closed='both'), axis=1)
df1.drop(columns=['intime', 'outtime'], inplace=True)
df2['opentime'] = df2.apply(lambda row: pd.Interval(
    row.open, row.close, closed='both'), axis=1)
df2.drop(columns=['open', 'close'], inplace=True)
```

Note: If for some reason the "original" time columns are needed,
don't drop them.

Then merge them and filter out "wrong" rows:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='visitto', right_on='location')
df3 = df3[df3.apply(lambda row: row.visittime.overlaps(row.opentime), axis=1)]
```

No loops or row iterations, just calls of *Pandas* metods.

Comment: "No loops or row iterations" You're doing implicit Python loops all throughout this example...

Comment: Of course, somewhere "under the hood" *Pandas* runs some loop, just like in many more methods. But at least programming by the end is easier, as he is free from programming such loops.